# Remove multiple lines from a given match until an empty line

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

On a unix system I have a file and I need to remove all lines that would match `Package: <PKG_NAME>` until an empty line is found. Here is an example, I would need to remove `terminfo` information:

```
...
Package: kmod-usb-storage
Version: 5.4.218-1
Depends: kernel (= 5.4.218-1-0c02597a113d34441a9bfe9294e3fb84), kmod-scsi-core, kmod-usb-core
Status: install user installed
Architecture: mips_24kc
Installed-Time: 1667822688
Auto-Installed: yes

Package: terminfo
Version: 6.2-1
Depends: libc
Status: install user installed
Architecture: mips_24kc
Installed-Time: 1667816896

Package: libuci-lua
Version: 2020-10-06-52bbc99f-5
Depends: libc, libuci20130104, liblua5.1.5
Status: install user installed
Architecture: mips_24kc
Installed-Time: 1667816896
Auto-Installed: yes
...
```

Afterwards I need to have no information about `terminfo`:

```
...
Package: kmod-usb-storage
Version: 5.4.218-1
Depends: kernel (= 5.4.218-1-0c02597a113d34441a9bfe9294e3fb84), kmod-scsi-core, kmod-usb-core
Status: install user installed
Architecture: mips_24kc
Installed-Time: 1667822688
Auto-Installed: yes

Package: libuci-lua
Version: 2020-10-06-52bbc99f-5
Depends: libc, libuci20130104, liblua5.1.5
Status: install user installed
Architecture: mips_24kc
Installed-Time: 1667816896
Auto-Installed: yes
...
```

I would be using this functionality inside a shell script, I have tried using `sed` and `awk` with no useful results, I couldn't figure out this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably get away with:

```
 awk '!/terminfo/' RS= ORS='\n\n'
```

Setting RS to the empty string causes `awk` to treat each section as a record ("section" meaning chunk of text delimited by an empty line, often called a "paragraph"), so you just print the ones that don't match the string `terminfo`.  To be more precise, you might want to use:

```
awk '!/^Package: terminfo/' RS= ORS='\n\n'
```

but that doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: FWIW I'd make it `awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '$2 != "terminfo"'` if the first script wasn't robust enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `sed '/terminfo/,/^$/d'`. This will delete from a line containing `terminfo` till an empty line is found.

See [How to print lines between two patterns, inclusive or exclusive (in sed, AWK or Perl)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns/) for more such problems dealing with multiple lines.

Comment: This will work as intended only if you use `sed -r`.

Comment: @rwst why do you need `-r` here? There are no ERE metacharacters used. (Also, `-E` is more portable over `-r` these days)